# Tuples in python to 3D matrix

Tags: python

I have a list of lists in python that contains the score of users in a game with different courses and levels. My tuple (users, courses, levels, scores). I ve got 20 users 4 courses and 10 levels. What I want is to create a 3D matrix which will have as dimensions users-courses-levels and as a value user score.  My tuples are as of the following:

```
(110, u'Math', 1, 5)
(110, u'Sports', 1,  5)
(110, u'Geography', 1, 10)
(112, u'History', 1,  9)
(112, u'History', 2,  10)
... ... ... ... ... ... ..
```

How can I create the 3D matrix (putting zero in the fields that I dont have data)?

Comment: By 3-D matrix do you mean a standard Python list of lists of lists -- or do you mean something in `numpy`? If the latter, you should add the appropriate tag.

Comment: @JohnColeman I think op actually wants a list of dictionary of lists...

Comment: Just for beginning a list of lists of lists.

Comment: @Dunno Perhaps that is what the user *should* want. Hard to tell. I would prefer a dictionary whose keys consist of 3-element tuples if I understand their problem.

Comment: @konstantin How is that supposed to work? Please show the desired output for your input example.

Comment: I want a list of 20 items which includes 3 lists of 10 items 20x3x10. And fill it with the value of score. The rest to be zero.

Comment: @konstantin That makes no sense. Again: Please show the desired output for your input example (just with the shown five entries would be enough, I think).

Comment: By wanting to use lists rather than dictionaries you seem to be throwing away information. For example, which of the second indices correspond to "Math"? `0`? `1`? Should we sort the disciplines first? These sort of questions would need to be answered if you use lists. Why not just use the string `"Math"` as the index -- in other words -- why not just use dictionaries? They are as easy to iterate over as lists, and would seem to be a more natural fit for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the data in that form, you could do something like:

```
data = [(110, 'Math', 1, 5),
(110, 'Sports', 1,  5),
(110, 'Geography', 1, 10),
(112, 'History', 1,  9),
(112, 'History', 2,  10)] #I'm using Python 3 -- u'' is superfluous

dataDict = {(x,y,z):w for x,y,z,w in data}

users = [110,112] #extend as needed. Also -- easily grabbed by code
subjects = ['Math', 'Sports', 'Geography', 'History'] #etc
levels = [1,2] #etc.

#first create a matrix of the right shape initialized to zeros:

dataMatrix = [[[0 for k in range(len(levels))] for j in range(len(subjects))] for i in range(len(users))]

#then load the nonzeros:

for i,u in enumerate(users):
    for j,s in enumerate(subjects):
        for k,l in enumerate(levels):
            if (u,s,l) in dataDict: dataMatrix[i][j][k] = dataDict[u,s,l]
```

To view it, do something like:

```
>>> for layer in dataMatrix: print(layer)

[[5, 0], [5, 0], [10, 0], [0, 0]]
[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0], [9, 10]]
```

the first layer is the 2-D matrix corresponding to the first user, etc.

Having done all this -- I really don't see any reason anybody would want to use `dataMatrix` rather than `dataDict`.