# Read lines from text as a list in Python

Tags: python

I am read data from text file. Every line of my data have the following structure

```
(110, 'Math', 1, 5)
(110, 'Sports', 1,  5)
(110, 'Geography', 4, 10)
(112, 'History', 1,  9)
....
```

and when I am reading the data from the file it is parsed as a string. So for all the lines I parse the data in a list of strings. However I want to create a list of lists with the 4 different elements (intengers and strings). How can I read the file elementwise and not parse it as string?

My code for read the file is the following:

```
data1 = [line.strip() for line in open("data.txt", 'r')]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that the format is always as you described (i.e. corresponds to the Python tuple syntax), this is easily done with [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> ast.literal_eval("(110, 'Math', 1, 5)")
(110, 'Math', 1, 5)
```

So, the full code is:

```
import ast
with open('data.txt') as fp:
    data = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in fp]
```

Comment: @Chris_Rands, it's even better to make a generator.

Comment: @skovorodkin generator is better, but that's out of the scope and left as an exercise :)

Comment: Or `map(ast.literal_eval, fp)`.

Comment: @bereal, yeah :) I answered to Chris but he deleted his comment. He advised to factor out `data` list and append to it in a loop.

Comment: @StefanPochmann if you're in Python3, `map` is lazy and reading from the file will be postponed. So when we exit the `with` context, the file will be closed, and attempt of iterating through the generator will fail.

Comment: @bereal Good point, though you can just slap `list(...)` around it if needed. Still shorter and I like it better :-). And the `u'Math'` in konstantin's [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39573129/tuples-in-python-to-3d-matrix) makes me suspect he's using Python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Do as follow :

```
data1 = [line.strip(')').strip('(').split() for line in open("data.txt", 'r')]
```

Comment: cast them to integers using `int(number)`